# Is Hibernate flush() synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: java, hibernate, asynchronous, flush

I am doing some test in which the flush and clear is not visible inmediately. Waiting for Hibernate to make the flush solves the problem.  Does it means that flush is asynchronous? Is there any official Hibernate documentatio about it?

This fails:

```
@Test
public void doTest()
   Entity oldData = myDAO.load(1L);
   oldData.setField("foo");

   myDAO.update( oldData);     
   flushAndClear();

   oldData= myDAO.load(oldData.getId()); // Reload
   assertThat(oldData.getField() , notNullValue());
}
```

But this works:

```
@Test
public void doTest()
   Entity oldData = myDAO.load(1L);
   oldData.setField("foo");

   myDAO.update( oldData);      
   flushAndClear();

   Thread.sleep(1000);  /** WAITING SOME TIME*/
   oldData= myDAO.load(oldData.getId()); // Reload
   assertThat(oldData.getField() , notNullValue());    
}
```

flushAndClear is just:

```
getCurrentSession().flush();
getCurrentSession().clear();
```

Comment: You're showing irrelevant code. What's inside `fooInsert()`, `flushAndClear()` and `checkIsInserted()`?

Comment: What I need to know is if after flush is returned I have a guaranty that the flush process is already completed.  Why is the code relevant?

Comment: Code is always relevant when you're asking a question about code. You could be doing all sorts of stupid things inside the methods, which would then cause undefined or erratic behaviour.

Comment: Added some code but it is really a simplification

Comment: The question is pretty simple with or without code: "Is flush synchronous?", not "how do i do x?"  Providing a clever way to make the above code above work without the sleep would not answer the basic question.